# how to dynamically load css names into django templates without cluttering the view

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a django app and I retrieve there "theme" value from memcached in views.py and pass it to several templates.
What I've achieved is to be able to switch jqueryui theme of various templates system-wide.

Here is an example of the template:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "jquery-ui-1.11.4/themes/"%}{{theme}}/jquery-ui.css">
```

The problem is that I need to retrieve and pass the theme for various view end points and if I forget to do it for one of them, then pf course the theme will not be found.
Is there a better way? Maybe using template tags?

Answer (score 0):

Use`context processor`

In app/mycontexts.py

```
def mytheme(request):
        return {
            'theme':"themename",
        }
```

Then in settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    #your contxt processors
    "path.to.app.mycontexts.mytheme", 
)
```

For django >= 1.7

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                #your contxt processors
                "path.to.app.mycontexts.mytheme", 
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Then you will get `{{theme}}` in every view.No need to pass specifically in every every view.

Comment: but this cannot be changed by the users. I'd like this to be modifiable by the admin from the web interface.